# how to rotate uibutton like this in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiview, cgaffinetransform

[image]

how to rotate uibutton like this in iphone sdk.....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have an IBOutlet Object.

```
theButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / -4);
```

If you want to create run time button on view.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIButton *btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 44)];
    btn.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / -4);
    [btn setTitle:@"RakeshBhatt" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view addSubview:btn];
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `M_PI` :/

Comment: @Dauwe Maan - Ok - I used M_PI. I agree it's preferable to use M_PI.

Answer (score 4):

```
theButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI / 4);
```

(Note: π/4 = 45°.)

Comment: Nop ! please check - that makes wrong rotation - not as per sample image.

Comment: @sugar: Ah the UIKit coordinates is in the opposite direction. See update.

Answer (score 2):

Recently i have done this, I rotate 5 button in different angles.

Here is the example:

```
UIButton *typewritterButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];             

typewritterButton.frame = CGRectMake(15, 165, 130, 25);

typewritterButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((0.0174)*135);

[m_overlay addSubview:typewritterButton];
```

definitely it will work for you.

use this `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((0.0174)*135);`

just change the value of 135 that is the angle in which you want to rotate the object.

Let me know if there is any problem.

Answer (score 1):

rotate to degree

```
#define degreesToRadians(x) (M_PI * (x) / 180.0)
```

then use / 90 is the degree:

```
button.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadians(90));
```

Answer (score 1):

The Swift version:

`button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(-M_PI_4))`